# How do I combine two indexer fields using AND?

Tags: lucene, liferay

```
searchQuery.addExactTerm(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK,"msCode");
searchQuery.addExactTerm("icsCode",ics);
```

This is  not  giving  me results  based  on AND  Conditions.  It is just searching the field and giving results.  Please help in constructing an AND query in lucene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addRequiredTerm` instead of `addExactTerm`:

```
searchQuery.addRequiredTerm(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK,"msCode");
searchQuery.addRequiredTerm("icsCode",ics);
```

Comment: The prob is that I have  seven fields  and to be searched  for and all  are  non mandatory  fields  if am giving  addRequiredTerm  its giving  nul pointer  exception  I  guess to  use addRequiredTerm  we  should have all input fields  filled by user pl help  :(

Comment: I would just avoid adding empty fields to the query.

Comment: Sir so do I have  to  use  If conditions  here to  check the entered  term is empty or not?If that is the case I have to  write  a lot of conditions?

Comment: Yep, seven of them, by the sound.  Personally, I don't see the problem.  I don't think checking your inputs is such an unusual or burdensome activity.